# MVC3 ASP.NET AJAX without Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd prefer to use spans within anchors for formatting purposes of my links. I can do this for html links with

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ViewMore","Post")">
    <span style="float:right;">View More</span>
</a>
```

I'd like to do the same for AJAX links but I've only found the ActionLink command.

`@Ajax.ActionLink("View Another", "Post", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" })`

What is the AJAX helper method similar to Url.Action?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use , assign an id to this anchor tag and use [jquery `.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on that.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ViewMore","Post")" id="linkViewMore">
    <span style="float:right;">View More</span>
</a>


$('#linkViewMore').click(function () {

 $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: ,
        data: ,
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                            },
        error: function (xhr, status) {


        }
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to insert a span for your link as opposed to just styling the link, perhaps with the addition of a class?

EDIT: In response to the comments, the Ajax.ActionLink() has largely the same properties as Html.ActionLink() and looking through the Html.ActionLink() api there isn't anything which easily allows the injection of a span inside the  element.

I would imagine you options would be to either write you own wrapper function which perhaps extends the existing helper functions, or to wrap your `<a>` in a `<span>` as opposed to the other way round.

Comment: "For formatting purposes" - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/ Specifically sliding doors.

Comment: Isn't the only requirement of said techniques that you have two HTML elements to use, could you not use an <ul>/<li> as per the example on ALA?

Comment: Your neglecting the point, if the button was by itself I would not want an unordered list with one list item containing a link, thats lengthy to code and poor HTML.

Comment: That is a fair point, I was considering purely a navigational list if I'm honest.